# Why would WPF render my controls twice?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a complex, multi-threaded WPF application which  works relatively well. Sometimes the controls of a dialog gets rendered twice on different positions. The result of this is an unreadable dialog.

Below is an example of an own written popup (opaque background with buttons on it), but it also happens on normal dialogs. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: How are the controls being created? Post some code.

Comment: If this doesn't occur on all machines, you might try disabling hardware acceleration for WPF.  If that resolves the issue, update your video card drivers.  Note that the referenced registry entries don't exist by default and have to be created. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx

Comment: Posting some Code is my Problem. It can occur once a month or more often. It is in all Dialogs which my application opens. Also in the most simple ones (1 Grid, 2 labels and a button). When the error occurs once, it happens 50/50 on all dialogs until i reboot the machine/PC.

The hardwareacceleration might be a nice try, and i will check it. But when i remember right, it happened on my developer PC aswell, where i have a very good graphic card.

Also search by google, i cannot even define the problem exactly so i get some hits. was already searching for 3+ hours...

any suggestions?